# Function to find local maximum

Tags: python, max

I have numpy vectors in which I want to locate the maximum value within a restricted index range.  The vector may contain NaN values.  I haven't been able to find a solution in numpy's max functions that handles both NaN's and subranges.  Does Python have a solution?

EXAMPLE: I want the second maximum (5.), between the 7th and the 11th position inside the array.

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([3, np.nan, 5.3, 7., 8,5., 0, 1, 3, 5., 2.4, .1, .3, 0.5])
c = np.nanmax(a)
d = np.nanargmax(b)
```

I tried to build my own function; it fails because of the NaN's -- and it's ugly. See below.

```
def rightmax(vector,s,f):
    l = 0
    peak = 0
    ml = 0
    for val in vector:
        if l < s or l >= f:
            continue
        elif val > peak:
            peak = val
            ml = l       
        l = l+1
    return peak, ml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you wanted this in Python; does this handle things for you?  Python simply ignores NaN values in most of its built-in functions.

```
import numpy as np

def local_max(a, start, finish):
    local = a[start:finish+1]
    loc_max = max(local)
    loc_pos = local.index(loc_max) + start
    return loc_max, loc_pos

data = [3, np.nan, 5.3, 7.0, 8, 5.0, 0, 1, 3, 5.0, 2.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5]

print local_max(data, 7, 11)
print local_max(data, 0, 5)
```

Comment: I get a error message: "object has no attribute index". what can it be?

Comment: You're running my code as it appears?  What version of Python do you have?  Mine is on 2.7 (lowest common denominator).

Comment: This is a nice solution to give you the max value between the requested start and finish indexes. This is not the same as the 'last local maxima' which is what I think the Claudia is looking for based on her comment to my answer...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to find the last local maxima in the array. I.e. in your example there are two local maxima of 8 and 5. at positions 4 and 9 respectively (0 based array counting). So you are looking for an answer of 5., 9. Assuming I've interpreted this correctly then just grabbing the max values isn't going to get you the answer. You need to find the maxima as the values go up and down along the vector.

You can use argrelextrema from scipy.signal to find the maxima. However it does not handle nan values without some treatment.

Assuming the nan values should not affect the outcome then you could safely replace them by interpolating between adjacent values e.g. using a simple average. e.g. in your example array you could process it to replace np.nan with (5.3 + 3)/2. Giving 4.15 (this ensures you don't promote a nan to a minima or maxima accidentally which could happen if you assume either a very small or very large value to replace them). Once you have done this you can apply argrelextrema easily:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
# array processed to replace nan values
b = np.array([3, np.nan, 5.3, 7., 8,5., 0, 1, 3, 5., 2.4, .1, .3, 0.5])
mask = np.isnan(data)
b[mask] = np.interp(np.flatnonzero(mask), np.flatnonzero(~mask), b[~mask])
c = argrelextrema(b, np.greater)
maxIdx = c[-1] #last element of c
maxVal = b[maxIdx]
```

Comment: yes, that is what I need to do. I have to encounter the maximum at a specific range of time. Most of the time it is the last maxima. Thanks for showing me the agrelextrema function. Unfortunately I have to handle also nan.

Comment: I didn't add the nan processing - it is easy enough to do this and I have given a  reasonable approach in the answer which will not affect the correct identification of the last local maxima in the vector. Something like this should do it: mask = np.isnan(b)
b[mask] = np.interp(np.flatnonzero(mask), np.flatnonzero(~mask), b[~mask]). I've updated my answer above.

Comment: You first approach was already great. In my case I have several matrices and I can't handle nan's one by one.So your second approach is better. I will test it as soon as possible. But please check maxIdx and maxVal... They are returnin the entire tuple with the maximum and the index. And thank for your answer.